# Search and replace the following in vi

Tags: linux, vim, centos, vi

Hi I want to replace the occurrence of [x] with [] in vi editor

I have used the following command

```
:%s/[x]/[]
```

and it gives me [[]], how to update my command so that I get desired result.

Comment: Try `\[x\]` perhaps

Comment: Hi n.m this works. Thanks. Could you post this as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace:

- It once (the first occurrence on the current line) with: `:s/\[x\]/[]/`
- It everywhere on the current line with `:s/\[x\]/[]/g`
- The first occurence on every line with `:%s/\[x\]/[]/`
- It everywhere `:%s/\[x\]/[]/g`

(Obviously you must make sure you are in command mode, use the esc-key for this)